# when i transfer data from JList to another one i faced a duplicate

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I faced a problem when I click on item to transfers it to another list
it duplicated ! and if I select by using keyboard arrows its not !

[image: here a picture when I clicked on ice cream]

and my code

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {  
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        model2.addElement(list.getSelectedValuesList());
    }
});
```

Comment: is it possible that the `ListSelectionListener` listener is added multiple times?

Comment: I dont know :@ what you suggest ?

Comment: @Yazan , thanx for help i found a solution after thinking in your comment :) by using  :  if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting())

Comment: good to hear that you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution , by using : `if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting())`